# Printing field item attributes with Twig / Drupal 8

Tags: entities, 8, theming

In Drupal 7, I can do this in a custom field template to print the alt tag of an image:

```
<?php print $item['#item']['alt']; ?>
```

And though "item" seems to be a variable in Twig / drupal 8 fields, I can't seem to do the same thing. I've tried these:

```
{{ item.alt }}
{{ item.item.alt }}
```

These don't work but I don't get any errors either. [Looking at the API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!field!templates!field.html.twig/8) does not give me much insight. I saw [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mortendk/6610523) but again, no alt tag rendered separately. My image is rendering the alt tag as i can see it in the code though.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://drupal.org/node/2042773

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax to print the alt tag in that case is this:

```
{{ item['#item'].alt }}
```

Twig in Drupal 8 doesn't deal with hash keys like `#item` in render arrays cleanly. Part of the problem is that `#` signifies a comment in Twig, so `{{ item.#item.alt }}` wouldn't work.

There is the possibility of working around this with a Twig extension to allow drilling down into hash attributes with the syntax `{{ item.item.alt }}` but I'm not sure if anyone is working on that. I should mention that Twig extensions can be added in contrib as well.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I could not find any documentation in regard to this, is there any reference you can point me to?

Comment: Things like this should probably be added under https://drupal.org/theme-guide/8 when they are specific to Twig + Drupal. I can see this potentially fitting in to https://drupal.org/node/1918824, maybe under Variables?

Comment: See also https://drupal.org/node/2160611 :)

Comment: I added this example to http://drupal.org/node/1918824, as suggested by @Cottser, and added a comment pointing to the core issue that he filed.

Comment: On Drupal 8 `{{ item['#item'].alt }}` doesn’t work for me. Instead, other solution by @Hugo `{{ item.content['#item'].alt }}` is ok.

Answer (score 3):

I achieved printing the alt attribute of my field using this line `{{ item.content['#item'].alt }}`

Comment: On Drupal 8 `{{ item['#item'].alt }}` doesn’t work for me. Your solution `{{ item.content['#item'].alt }}` works (I’ve seen seen a discussion here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2160611)